# Convert string to object in typescript?

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I am trying to validate a glob expression using [Is-Valid-Glob](https://github.com/micromatch/is-valid-glob) which accepts string and array. The value which needs to be validated is received from a text field. The problem is that if we pass an invalid glob expression it produces the wrong result as every input is received as a string. For example:- If user inputs [] (invalid glob) its gets assigned to model variable as string '[]' and validation is done on '[]' instead of [] value.
Is there a way by which we convert the value from string variable to object variable (only the value should not get type) and do validation?

PS: I am using Angular 2.

Comment: please consider reading the [**asking help**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a valid and quality post

Comment: share example with us

Comment: Have you tried using eval?

Answer (score 6):

You can use JSON.parse to convert from string to objects:

```
     var x = require('is-valid-glob');
     var y = '[]';//'foo/*.js' any user provided string
     // this will check if the user has provided an array object if so it 
     //will do a json.parse to remove the '' and then verify the string for a glob.
     x(y[1] !== '['?y:JSON.parse(y));
```

Comment: Hi @Vikramjit, I am using the similar hack serves the purpose. Looking for a    more satisfiable solution. Also, need to add cases for {} (invalid glob), it will pass in this scenario

Answer (score 3):

Try with eval it is used to convert string into equivalent object for an example,

```
var a="[]";
console.log(a);// this will print "[]" as a string.
console.log(eval(a));// this will print an array object. With 0 length array object.
```

Comment: thanks, @deepak, eval will not be helpful in case of strings. eg "foo/*.js" (valid glob).

Answer (score -2):

We can use Object.assign({},object) to convert string into object.

Comment: Doesn't work. In case of a string, it splits the string to an array where each element is a single character from that string.